# tikz: sloped text orientation

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I ensure that `Text 3` (as well as `Text 1'`) has the same orientation as `Text 1` and `Text 2`?

I want one turn of my head to be sufficient to be able to read the text.

---

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, node distance=3cm, every node/.style={sloped},]
    \node (a)                    {a};
    \node (c) [below right of=a] {c};
    \node (b) [below left  of=c] {b};
    \path (a) [bend right] edge node [above] {Text 1}  (b)
          (b) [bend right] edge node [above] {Text 1'} (a)
          (b) [bend right] edge node [above] {Text 2}  (c)
          (a) [bend left]  edge node [above] {Text 3}  (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Updated example]

Comment: The image looks quite fine to me. Turning `Text 3` upside-down would change the angle from about -45° to about 135°. I can read text without turning my head, if it is not to much sloped, but my neck is not as flexible to be able to turn my head to a full right angle. Thus I would have to make a handstand or turn the monitor instead.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek thanks, I can see your point (but want to do it anyhow ;)). I tried to give a better example (added `Text 1'`). Turning my head now (to read `Text 1`) results in `Text 1'` being upside down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text labels can be rotated:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, node distance=3cm, every node/.style={sloped},]
    \node (a)                    {a};
    \node (c) [below right of=a] {c};
    \node (b) [below left  of=c] {b};
    \path (a) [bend right] edge node [above] {Text 1}  (b)
          (b) [bend right] edge node [above, rotate=180] {Text 1'} (a)
          (b) [bend right] edge node [above] {Text 2}  (c)
          (a) [bend left]  edge node [above, rotate=180] {Text 3}  (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

This fixes the issue with `Text 1'`. The other case `Text 3` is now upside-down, much less readable IMHO, see my [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331231/tikz-sloped-text-orientation/331244#comment811708_331231) to the question.

A variation with less slopes, where the labels are moved a little to the arrow start points:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, node distance=3cm, every node/.style={sloped},]
    \node (a)                    {a};
    \node (c) [below right of=a] {c};
    \node (b) [below left  of=c] {b};
    \path (a) [bend right] edge node [above, pos=.35] {Text 1}  (b)
          (b) [bend right] edge node [above, pos=.35] {Text 1'} (a)
          (b) [bend right] edge node [above, pos=.4] {Text 2}  (c)
          (a) [bend left]  edge node [above, pos=.35] {Text 3}  (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

IMHO, the label angles should be in the range -90° to +90° as the default behavior to avoid upside-down labels:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, node distance=3cm, every node/.style={sloped},]
    \path
      \foreach \a in {0, 15, ..., 345} {
        (0, 0) edge node[above, pos=.8]{\color{blue}\a\textdegree} (\a:4cm)
      }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Changing the slope for `Text 3` is a *manual* intervention. An automated solution would need general *rules*. If these rules require that the label orientation depends on each other, this would also add a serious complexity level, where the result is quite unclear to be an improvement at all.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same without (manually) adding `rotate=180` to the affected edges?

Comment: @DisplayName See the updated answer.